Proving that cheybeshev's inequality if asymptoticall tight for these random variables.
I was solving some exercise from Prof. Goemans' course notes for the course "Principles of Discrete Applied Mathematics" he gave in 2015. I am studying this area by myself and I am stuck in the following exercise. Please give me some hints.
Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{d}$ be independent random variables that take value 1 or -1 , each with probability $1 / 2$. For each $S \subseteq[d]$, define the random variable $Y_{S}=\prod_{i \in S} X_{i}$. i) Show that the variables $\left\{Y_{S}\right\}$ are pairwise independent. ii) Let $Z=\sum_{S \subseteq D} Y_{S}$. Show that Chebyshev's Inequality is asymptotically tight for $Z$.
My attempt for the first part: Say $Y_{S_1}$ and $Y_{S_2}$ are two random variables let $|S_1 \cap S_2| \geq 0$. If we combine those $X_s$s such that $s \in S_1 \cap S_2$, we get another random variable $X'_{S_1\cap S_2} = \prod\limits_{s\in S_1 \cap S_2} X_s$ which also takes value 1 or -1 with probability $1/2$. Hence $Y_{S_1} = X'_{S_1\cap S_2}\cdot \left(\prod\limits_{s\in S_1 - S_2} X_s\right)$ and $Y_{S_2} = X'_{S_1\cap S_2}\cdot \left(\prod\limits_{s\in S_2 - S_1} X_s\right)$. But I could not proceed further. It would be helpful if someone can guide me.
PS: I guess he means $[d]$ by $D$ in the question. Also, I ensure that this is not part of some course I am currently attending.

Note that $Y_S$ is also Rademacher distributed (i.e. it takes value $1$ or $-1$ , each with probability $1/2$), since the product of two independent Rademacher variables is Rademacher distributed.
$\mathrm{(i)}$
Pick $S,T\subset [d]$ with $S\neq T$. We want to show that $$\mathbb P [Y_S = s, Y_T = t] = \mathbb P [Y_S = s]\,\mathbb P[ Y_T = t], \,\forall s,t\in\{\pm1\}.$$
If $S$ and $T$ are disjoint this is straightforward since $Y_S$ and $Y_T$ are functions of different $X_i$ and the latter are mutually independent. Now, consider the case in which $S$ and $T$ are not disjoint. Suppose WLOG that $S\setminus T\neq\emptyset$ (the case $T\setminus S\neq\emptyset$  is similar). Using law of total probability and the fact that $Y_S = Y_{S\setminus T}\,Y_{S\cap T}$we get that $$\begin{align}\mathbb P [Y_S = s, Y_T = t] &= \mathbb P [Y_S = s, Y_T = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=1] \, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=1]\\&+\mathbb P [Y_S = s, Y_T = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=-1] \, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\\&= \mathbb P [Y_{S\setminus T} = s, Y_T = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=1] \, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=1]\\&+\mathbb P [Y_{S\setminus T} = -s, Y_T = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=-1] \, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\\&= \mathbb P [Y_{S\setminus T} = s\vert Y_{S\cap T}=1] \, \mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=1]\, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=1]\\&+\mathbb P [Y_{S\setminus T} = -s\vert Y_{S\cap T}=-1] \, \mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\\&= \mathbb P [Y_{S\setminus T} = s] \, \mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=1]\, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=1]\\&+\mathbb P [Y_{S\setminus T} = -s] \, \mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\\&=  \frac{1}{2}\, \mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=1]\, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=1]\\&+\frac{1}{2}\, \mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t\vert Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\, \mathbb P [Y_{S\cap T}=-1]\\&=\frac{1}{2}\,\mathbb P [Y_{ T} = t]=\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb P [Y_S = s]\,\mathbb P[ Y_T = t]
\end{align}$$
$\mathrm{(ii)}$
If $Y$ is Rademacher distributed, then $\mathbb E[Y] = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var}[Y]=1$. Hence, using linearity of the expectation we get $\mathbb E[Z] = 0$. Note that the variance of the sum of pairwise independent variables is equal to the sum of the variances, in fact
\begin{align}\mathrm{Var} [Z] &= \mathrm{Var}\Bigl[\sum_{S\subset[d]}Y_S\Bigr]=\sum_{S\subset[d]}\mathrm{Var}[Y_S]+\sum_{S,T\subset [d]\\S\neq T}\mathrm{Cov}[Y_S,Y_T]\\&=\sum_{S\subset[d]}\mathrm{Var}[Y_S]=\sum_{S\subset[d]}1=2^d.\end{align}
In the last equality, we have assumed that $Y_\emptyset=1$.
Chebyshev's inequality states that
$$\mathbb{P}(\lvert Z\rvert \ge t) \le \frac{2^d}{t^2},\,\forall t>0.$$
Note that the inequality is tight in the sense that we cannot find another bound lower than Chebyshev's since for $t=2^d$ we have
$$\mathbb P (\lvert Z \rvert\ge 2^d) = \mathbb P (Z=2^d)=\mathbb P (X_1=\dots=X_d = 1) = 2^{-d}=\frac{2^d}{(2^d)^2}$$

Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!
